# Unity Add Item on click to Inventory

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

Currently, I'm creating an RPG style game where the player has to click on certain "glowing" objects in order to obtain items that will be added to thier inventory in order to proceed to the next level. I've created the GUI inventory bar already and I can place items into the boxes, but I cannot figure out how I can import a GUI item on click to the inventory.
If anyone could give me some ideas or possible resources that I could look at to figure something out, that would be amazing.
Thank you.

Comment: When player click on GameObject destory it and check which GameObject was clicked and just add Icon or Script(or GameObject) to GUI.

Comment: Well I don't want the item destroyed exactly, but just turn the object off from being clicked and put whatever item that's attached to that object into the inventory, it would probably just be a jpeg image at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think your question is quite wide and lots depends on other thinks but let me put down some hints here, hope some of them will help you:

- To turn off an object use SetActive(false) on that object, this way it is still available for code but not clickable anymore
- For items (and this really depends on how you want to work with items in the game):

  1. either make these receivable items children of the glowing object and then just cjange its parent (item.transform.SetParent(bag.transfrom))or
  2. if you need just basic data about them create a MonoBehaviour script with the metadata and place it on the glowing object and after click copy them to your bag

If this didn't answer all what you wanted, please be more specific or put some example code here

**EDIT:**

I still think your question is too wide and you should specify it more but lets try second time:

let's assume that the glowing object has these images as Sprites and they are added in Editor or by some other script at runtime. Also the glowing object should have a reference to the bag object, again get it at runtime or in editor if possible. Then place this on click method into the gloving object component and that should do the trick:

```
public void OnClickOnGlowItem() {
  foreach(Sprite sprite in this.attachedItems)
    this.bagObjectInterface.AddNewItem(sprite);
}
```

Comment: It's not so much turning the item off or having them glow. It's taking a image from an array and importing it into the player's inventory and then checking if it's true or not.

Comment: OK, one question before I edit my answer, what do you mean by checking if it's true?

Comment: well the goal of the level is to obtain certain items in order to pass through a door. So I was thinking that there could be an Item Check sort of thing to make sure the player has all the "items" needed in order to unlock the door.

Comment: I think that you are looking for an easy solution for a wrong design. If you are implementing an RPG, transfering items is not about some image but about an instance of an object with some metadata. You need at least a class/script containing all the data about an item with the image its-self. Than the bag contains the list of these objects and on GUI you are showing the images. Based on some code you are checking if the bag contains all items for the level. This list you will have to stored in level configuration. But as  I said this is a wide solution to implement, not just image transfer.